# c++/WinRT Graphics interop to DirectX failing

Tags: c++, windows-runtime, directx

I'm trying to capture bitmap from screen via Capture Api, using `ID3D11Texture2D`.
Here is part of event handler:

```
void
ScreenGrabWinCaptureApi::OnFrameArrived(const winrt::Windows::Graphics::Capture::Direct3D11CaptureFramePool &sender,
                                        const winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable &) {
    auto frame = framePool.TryGetNextFrame();

    winrt::com_ptr<Windows::Graphics::DirectX::Direct3D11::IDirect3DDxgiInterfaceAccess> access;

    access = frame.as<Windows::Graphics::DirectX::Direct3D11::IDirect3DDxgiInterfaceAccess>();

    winrt::com_ptr<ID3D11Texture2D> frame_surface;

    winrt::check_hresult(
            access->GetInterface(winrt::guid_of<ID3D11Texture2D>(), frame_surface.put_void()));

//
// <other stuff here>
//
}
```

I cannot understand why `frame.as<Windows::Graphics::DirectX::Direct3D11::IDirect3DDxgiInterfaceAccess>();` is throwing exception, even can't understand what exception thrown.

I've tried to read dumps, and they are confusing me, as I have different exceptions in Release/Debug builds. In debug, there is window suggesting me to debug, and I think that the reason I havn't regular "process crash".

[crash window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2de6.png)

Here is fragment of **Debug** procdump call:

```
PS C:\Users\arkuzo\Procdump> .\procdump64.exe -e rds-wrtc.exe
.
.
.
[13:54:03] Exception: 40080201
[13:54:03] Exception: 40080201
[13:54:03] Exception: E06D7363.?AUhresult_class_not_registered@winrt@@
[13:54:08] The process has exited.
[13:54:08] Dump count not reached.
```

I've created dump after crash window appeared, and get following in `!analyze -v` output (I assume that is crash window call):

```
EXCEPTION_RECORD:  (.exr -1)
ExceptionAddress: 0000000000000000
   ExceptionCode: 80000003 (Break instruction exception)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 0

FAULTING_THREAD:  00004660

PROCESS_NAME:  rds-wrtc.exe

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0x80000003 - {          }                                           .

EXCEPTION_CODE_STR:  80000003

STACK_TEXT:  
0000001e`e5cfe308 00007ffa`21f08bf6     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00e50073 00000000`00000001 0000001e`00000001 : win32u!NtUserGetMessage+0x14
0000001e`e5cfe310 00007ff6`56a53285     : 00000000`00000000 0000001e`e5cff250 0000001e`e5cff250 00000000`0000018f : user32!GetMessageA+0x46
0000001e`e5cfe370 00000000`00000000     : 0000001e`e5cff250 0000001e`e5cff250 00000000`0000018f 00007ff6`80000000 : rds_wrtc!WinMain+0x1075
```

In **Release**, there is unhandled exception crash, and dump was succesfully created. Here is fragment of dump description:

```
This dump file has an exception of interest stored in it.
The stored exception information can be accessed via .ecxr.
(21bc.e2c): Security check failure or stack buffer overrun - code c0000409 (first/second chance not available)
Subcode: 0x7 FAST_FAIL_FATAL_APP_EXIT
```

Same error code in `!analyze -v` call.

What is original error? `40080201`, `c0000409` or `80000003`? How to know that? And how to fix `winrt::com_ptr::as` call (I've got 2 open source examples with same code running normally)?

Comment: Difficult to say. You should post a reproducing project somewhere.

Comment: Cannot do this because of NDA. Will continue work on my own. @SimonMourier also thanks :)